# PowerPoint VBA shape timing duration

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes, animatewithduration

I need help changing the duration time of an existing shape in a PowerPoint slide using vba.
All I can find is changing the duration of a new effect added.  I need to change the duration time of an existing shape with a defined timing duration.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general idea, please customize for your code:

```
Sub SetTiming()
    Dim EffAnim As Effect
    Set EffAnim = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(1)
    EffAnim.Timing.Duration = 5
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question.  Is the Item number the Index ID of the Shape?

Comment: The Item number will be the animation as shown on the Animation Pane. Item(3) will be the third animation down.

Comment: John,Thank you very much.  My app is now complete.